# Laravel Call to undefined method Illuminate\Database\Query\Builder::getTest()

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

When calling a query in Laravel 5.2, it shows me

BadMethodCallException in Builder.php line 2405:
Call to undefined method Illuminate\Database\Query\Builder::getTest()

The query is below:

```
$record = self::leftJoin("$customersTable as customers", 'customers.email', '=', "{$this->table}.email")

->whereRaw($where)
                ->where(function ($record) use ($criteria, $search_type, $persist){
$record->getTest($record, $criteria, $search_type, $persist);
                }); 
->orderBy($sort_by, $sort_dir)
->skip($offset)
->take($limit)
->get();
```

Comment: I'm using class Prospects extends Eloquent{

Comment: Where does that `getTest()` method comes from? Is it a relationship of one of your models? If yes, then please show us your all related models and their relationship.